# How to override the CRUD methods in tastypie?

Tags: python, django, crud, tastypie

As the title suggests I'd like to know **if** and **how** I can override the get and post methods of Tastypie.

For example, every time a user sends over a json file at the API endpoint, I don't want anything to be stored in the models and instead only return a small message back.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This example coming directly from Tastypie [Cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html):

```
from tastypie.utils import now
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyObject.objects.all()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(MyResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(start_date__gte=now)
```

Similar approach can be utilized for POST etc. as well. Hope it helps :)